# JavaScript: Split string by characters only or by characters + number if present

Tags: javascript

How can I split JavaScript string by characters OR by characters+numbers if present?

Example:

Just characters:

```
var items = "asdaasf";
//I am using
items.split('');
```

so that's okay.

Now if I have numbers:

```
var items = "a2sdaa5sf";
```

I want it to split into array so I have result like:

```
[a2,s,d,a,a5,s,f]
```

So that it counts as 1 character if letter is followed by a number.

Would I use regex? What would syntax be? I am not too familiar with RegEx.

Comment: What if you have multiple numbers in a row, like `"a2sd12a3"`? Do you want `["a2", "sd12", "a3"]` or `["a2", "sd1", "2", "a3"]`?

Comment: Didn't think of that, but yes ["a2", "sd12", "a3"]
in other words - numbers should not be considered as single characters, their parent will be the previous letter.

Comment: I think the result should rather be `["a2", "s", "d12", "a3"]`, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split on every position where the following character is a letter. This can be done with a [**lookahead**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
> "a2sd12a3".split(/(?=[a-z])/i)
["a2", "s", "d12", "a3"]
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, choosing as best as this answer was posted faster, seems fair.

Answer (score 1):

If you would just like to split it by character or character followed by number

```
var reg =  /([a-z]\d*)/g;
var myString = 'something'
myString.match(reg)
```

@Felix Kling answer is more elegant with the lookahead , but if you want to stick to simplest possible, assuming it always starts with a character.

Answer (score 1):

To complement @FelixKling's answer, without relying exclusively on a regex, you can reproduce the logic fairly easily:

```
var input = "a1b2c3de45f6gh78i9j0";

var chunks = [];
var accum = "";
var lastWasDigit = false;
var isDigitRex = /[0-9]/;

Array.from(input).forEach(function (i) {
  var isDigit = isDigitRex.exec(i);
  if (lastWasDigit && !isDigit) {
    chunks.push(accum);
    accum = "" + i;
  } else {
    accum += i;
  }
  lastWasDigit = isDigit;
})

console.log(chunks);
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar approach to *Abraham Adam*'s, but updated to include case-insensitivity, by using the following regex:   `/[a-z]\d*/ig`

```
var regexVal = /[a-z]\d*/ig;

var test1 = "asdaasf";
var test2 = "a2sdaa5sf";
var test3 = "a2sd12a3";
var test4 = "a1b2c3de45f6gh78i9j0";
var test5 = "a1b2c3De45f6gH78I9j0";

console.log(test1.match(regexVal));  // ["a", "s", "d", "a", "a", "s", "f"]
console.log(test2.match(regexVal));  // ["a2", "s", "d", "a", "a5", "s", "f"]
console.log(test3.match(regexVal));  // ["a2", "s", "d12", "a3"]
console.log(test4.match(regexVal));  // ["a1", "b2", "c3", "d", "e45", "f6", "g", "h78", "i9", "j0"]
console.log(test5.match(regexVal));  // ["a1", "b2", "c3", "D", "e45", "f6", "g", "H78", "I9", "j0"]
```

Comment: Does adding an `i` to an existing solution really require an answer? Why didn't you just comment?

Comment: I was typing up my solution at the same time as he was . . . I added the "intro" when I saw how similar our answers were.  With my examples and the slight difference in syntax (i.e., no parens in the regex), I decided to leave the answer up.